# Interchange of sup and min/max

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a function from couples of natural numbers and let $A$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Does it hold that

$$\max\{\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \;f(a,n)\;| \;a \in A\}=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \max\{f(a,n)\;| \;a \in A\}$$

and

$$\min \{\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \;f(a,n)\;| \;a \in A\}= \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \min\{f(a,n) \;| \;a \in A\}$$

?

And: if not, under which conditions does it hold?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The first holds unconditionally, the second will fail for general $f$.

Perhaps I will elaborate if you show some of your own work.

Comment: Thanks! Could you be so kind as to explain me (or just give me an hint about) how to prove the first? Here are some details on the function $f$. Suppose $g_{0}, g_{1},...$ is a non-decreasing sequence of functions in $[0,1]^{S}$. Let $\Delta_{0},\Delta_{1},...$ be an enumeration of probability distributions on $S$ such that for all $i$ the support $\lceil \Delta_{i} \rceil$ of $\Delta_{i}$ is finite. The function $f$ is defined as follows: $f(a,n)=\sum_{s \in \lceil \Delta_{a}\rceil} \Delta_{a}(s) \cdot g_{n}(s)$.

Comment: You could try to show that both sides equal $\sup\limits_{(a,n)\in A \times\Bbb N} f(a,n)$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you know where I could find theorems concerning sufficient condition for the second equality to hold?

Comment: No, I don't. But you'll need to use the specific definition of $f$ in any case, because it's false in general.